# For $\alpha\in(0^\circ;90^\circ)$ simplify $\sin^2\alpha+\tan^2\alpha+\sin^2\alpha.\cos^2\alpha+\cos^4\alpha$

Tags: trigonometry

For $\alpha\in(0^\circ;90^\circ)$ simplify $\sin^2\alpha+\tan^2\alpha+\sin^2\alpha\cdot\cos^2\alpha+\cos^4\alpha.$

My try: $\sin^2\alpha+\tan^2\alpha+\sin^2\alpha\cdot\cos^2\alpha+\cos^4\alpha=\sin^2\alpha+\dfrac{\sin^2\alpha}{\cos^2\alpha}+\sin^2\alpha\cdot\cos^2\alpha+\cos^4\alpha=\dfrac{\sin^2\alpha\cdot\cos^2\alpha+\sin^2\alpha+\sin^2\alpha\cdot\cos^4\alpha+\cos^6\alpha}{\cos^2\alpha}.$

This doesn't seem to help much.

Comment: Write the $sin^2$ with cos one as 1-cos^2

Comment: Try factoring $\sin^2\alpha$ out of the first two terms and $\cos^4\alpha$ out of the last two terms in the numerator.

Comment: @AdityaDwivedi, in the beginning, or to continue my try?

Comment: In the beginning

Comment: @AdityaDwivedi, thank you, but I am not sure I see how this helps.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig, thank you for the response! Also in the beginning?

Comment: $\sin^2(x)\cos^2(x)=\cos^2(x)-\cos^4(x)$

Comment: I was looking at your final expression when I made that suggestion.  See DatBoi's answer.  That said, Safdar's answer is also good.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're almost there!
$$\dfrac{\sin^2\alpha\cdot\cos^2\alpha+\sin^2\alpha+\overbrace{\sin^2\alpha\cdot\cos^4\alpha+\cos^6\alpha}}{\cos^2\alpha}$$
$$=\dfrac{\sin^2\alpha\cdot\cos^2\alpha+\sin^2\alpha+\cos^4(\alpha)(\cos^2(\alpha)+\sin^2(\alpha))}{\cos^2\alpha}$$
$$=\dfrac{\sin^2\alpha+ \overbrace{\sin^2\alpha\cdot\cos^2\alpha+\cos^4(\alpha)}}{\cos^2\alpha}$$
$$=\dfrac{\sin^2\alpha+\cos^2(\alpha)(\cos^2(\alpha)+\sin^2(\alpha))}{\cos^2\alpha}$$
$$=\dfrac{\overbrace{\sin^2\alpha+\cos^2(\alpha)}}{\cos^2\alpha}$$
$$=\dfrac{1}{\cos^2\alpha}$$
$$=\boxed{\sec^2(\alpha)}$$

Answer (score 4):

Express everything in terms of $ \cos \alpha=c $
$$ (1-c^2) + (1-c^2)/c^2 + (1-c^2) c^2 + c^4$$

$$= \dfrac{c^2-c^4+1-c^2+c^4-c^6+c^6}{c^2} = \dfrac{1}{c^2}$$

Answer (score 3):

Instead of dividing by $\cos^2\alpha$, you could do the following,

\begin{align}&\sin^2 \alpha + \tan^2 \alpha +\sin^2\alpha +\sin^2\alpha\cos^2\alpha + \cos^4\alpha\\ &= \sin^2 \alpha + \tan^2 \alpha +\sin^2\alpha +\cos^2\alpha(\sin^2\alpha + \cos^2\alpha) \\
 &= \sin^2 \alpha + \tan^2 \alpha + \cos^2\alpha
\\ &=1+\tan^2\alpha
\\ &=\sec^2\alpha \end{align}